# LUA: Having trouble understanding the difference between a.x and a[x]

Tags: lua

As the Lua manual says, newbies to the language fall into the trap of thinking both a.x and a[x] are more alike than different. I am one of those newbies, ahaha.

Why does a.x give nil in this, but a[x] gives 10 and a.x gives nil?

```
a ={}

x = "y"

a[x] = 10

 print(a[x])  --gives 10 for "y"

 print(a.x)  --gives nil for "x"

 print(a.y)  --give 10 for "y"
```

To be honest, I feel like I understand why the code above works, but I really want to know—conceptually— why:

```
invitems = {}

name = string.lower(name)

invitems[name] = "weapon"

print(invitems[name]) ----> gives weapon

print(invitems.name)  ----> gives nil

print(invitems.string.lower(name))  ----> gives weapon
```

Comment: `a.x` == `a["x"]`. There is no equivalent to `a[x]` in dot notation.

Comment: That last line of code shouldn't work, because you never gave `invitems` a `string` field. Did you mean `print(invitems[string.lower(name)])`?

Comment: search the Lua manual for syntactic sugar https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.1   this is very important to understand. also make sure that you knwo what a valid Lua name/identifier looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for table access in Lua is `<table>[<expression>]`. When you access a table using bracket notation, i.e., `a[x]`, the *expression* `x` is evaluated first, and the value of `x` is used as a table index.

On the other hand, `a.x` is *syntactic sugar* for the table access `a["x"]`. Here, the *string* `"x"` is taken to be the table index.

Consider this interaction in the REPL:

```
> a = {}
> x = "y"
> a[x] = 10
> a.x
nil
> a[x]
10
> a["y"]
10
> a.y
10
```

With `a[x] = 10`, the `x` first evaluates to the value `"y"`, and so the table accesses `a["y"]`, storing the value `10` there. But before that the table was empty; the attempt to access `a.x` is equivalent to `a["x"]`, and there is no value stored in `a` under the key `"x"`, so `nil` is returned. But note that you could also access the value `10` which was stored by using `a["y"]`, or `a.y` which is equivalent to `a["y"]`.

Or consider this continuation of the above interaction:

```
> a[1] = 42
> z = 1
> a[z]
42
> a.z
nil
> a["z"]
nil
> a["z"] = "forty-two"
> a.z
forty-two
> a[z]
42
```

Now `a[1]` assigns the value `42` to the table field with the key `1`. When `z` is given the value `1`, we can access the new value in the table with `a[z]` because `z` evaluates to `1`. But we can't access the value with `a.z` because there is no table field keyed to `"z"`. After `a["z"] = "forty-two"` there is a value keyed to `"z"`, and now it can be seen that `a.z` and `a[z]` are entirely different members of the table `a`.

Comment: Okay! I seeeeee now, thank you thank you for the explanation, I couldn't move past it till I truly understood it!

Answer (score 5):

`a[x]` is the more fundamental indexing construct. `a.x` is syntactic sugar for `a['x']`. So in `a[x]`, `x` is a variable name. In `a.x`, `x` is a literal string, which is unrelated to the variable `x`.